# Active directory management through a web page

Tags: active-directory

Before we rush off and build a custom solution what is a good pre-existing tool that allow active directory users to be managed through a web interface?  I'm after two general categories, either through one interface or through seperate sites:

**User self management**

- Change password when current password is known
- Request a password reset/account unlock to be sent to their email

**Admin tools**

- Locate a user account with simple search features (name, email, etc)
- Put users in/out of groups
- Update account details (address, phone number etc)
- reset passwords (bonus points if the reset will mail the new password to the email address stored in AD)

(AD level is 2003, and the web server that will be used is IIS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Identity Lifecycle Manager will do all of that and more.  Currently in Release Candidate status, you can download and try it here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver/ilm2/default.mspx

Answer (score 3):

[ADManager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/)  will handle your management points.

[Directory Update](http://www.directory-update.com/) will handle user self-servicing.

Answer (score 3):

[Softerra Adaxes](http://adaxes.com) software is able to fulfill all the requirements. You can download and try it free. There are some more useful features for users and admins.